# android eclipse: INSTALL_PARSE_FAILED_MANIFEST_MALFORMED

Tags: android, eclipse, widget, manifest, malformed

i am working on an app lately and i have never encountered a problem like this. I add a widget on my app via eclipse new activity-->widget and then when i try to run the app on my phone i get this error:

*Installation error: INSTALL_PARSE_FAILED_MANIFEST_MALFORMED
Please check logcat output for more details.
Launch canceled!*

I have already searched for this problem but every solution given is not helpful.

My manifest file is this. Is there an error i cannot get in it?
Is there any change the problem to be in something else and not in the manifest file?

Thanks

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.hotelreseration"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="17"
        android:targetSdkVersion="23" />

    <permission
        android:name="com.example.hotelreseration.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature" />

    <uses-feature
        android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
        android:required="true" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/getaroom"
        android:label="@string/welcome"
        android:theme="@style/AppBaseTheme" >

        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
            android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />

         <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
            android:value="AIzaSyCMaGYB0vEk8iiQSa29boQF2B58xu3mZjE" />


         <activity
            android:name=".SelectUserActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_select_user"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".LoginActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".CreateAccountActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_activity_create_account"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".MainScreenActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_main_screen"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".ForgotPassActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_forgot_pass"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".MainTestActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_main_test"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
        </activity>
         <activity
            android:name=".SettingsActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_settings"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".Fragment_reservations"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_fragment3"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".ListBlackFontActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_list_black_font"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".FragmentAddHotel2"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_fragment_add_hotel2"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
        </activity>




        <activity
            android:name="$NavigationDrawer.Fragment_hotels"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_fragment_hotels"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="$NavigationDrawer.Fragment_info"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_fragment1"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="$NavigationDrawer.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_main"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="$NavigationDrawer.Fragment_maps"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_fragment_maps"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="$NavigationDrawer.AddHotelActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_add_hotel"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="$NavigationDrawer.FragmentAddRoom"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_fragment_add_room"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
        </activity>


        <receiver android:name=".AppWidget" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.appwidget.action.APPWIDGET_UPDATE" />
            </intent-filter>

            <meta-data
                android:name="android.appwidget.provider"
                android:resource="@xml/app_widget_info" />
        </receiver>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: Any help on this please?

Comment: Does the logcat output provide more details like it says it will?

Comment: Nop, i checked.. I just found it. The problem is the $NavigationDrawer in front of some of the activities.I removed it and it worked. Thanks btw :)